# From queue() to Promise

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to use a [map graph](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/bubblemap_template.html) in a Vue.js component.
My problem is that when I setup my component, it tells me a warning:

> "export 'queue' (imported as 'd3') was not found in 'd3'

Now, I saw that in the new versions of D3 the function `queue()` has been removed. I wanted to know how to convert that code in order to make it work with the new version of D3. In particular, I think the problem is here:

```
d3.queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/world.geojson")  // World shape
    .defer(d3.csv, "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/data_gpsLocSurfer.csv") // Position of circles
    .await(ready);
```

I am a beginner in D3, so I saw some similar questions here, but nothing close enough to what I want to achieve.